# Extraer números de un String de un TXT

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo de texto con muchas strings en varias líneas como la siguiente:

STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1993201 SYNFQCTest Quiero extraer el numero que sigue al texto FFN. Este numero lo quiero guardar en una variable para después operar con él.

¿Cómo puedo extraer únicamente el número 1993201? Este numero puede variar, no siempre será este, así que me gustaría tener un método genérico para poder reutilizarlo.

He intentado lo siguiente pero no me ha funcionado:

```
f = r"archivo.txt"
a = 'FFN'
b = "SYNFQC"

print (c = f[a:b])
```

Error que me muestra:

```
print (c = f[a:b])
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an index method
```

Gracias.

Comment: Buenas, ¿podrías incluir las cosas que has hecho, intentado o investigado?

Comment: @SergioGarridoDomínguez he intentado delimitar la búsqueda en el fichero para que me imprima los valores que se encuentran entre FFN y SYN, pero no me funciona el método ya que me indica que debe realizarse con integers y no con strings.

Comment: Prueba realizando una búsqueda de la posición de FFN y SYNFQC y utilizar dichas posiciones.
`ffn = f.index("FFN")
synfqc = f.index("SYNFQC")
print(f[ffn:synfqc])`

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser con Python? Con `grep` es apenas una línea.

Comment: @SergioGarridoDomínguez tu método no me ha funcionado pero el planteamiento me ha servido para encontrar la solución. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo he solucionado usando el siguiente código:

```
with open(r"archivo.txt", 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        f, l = 28, 35
        x = (line[f:l])
```

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de tu respuesta aceptada, solamente te servirá si en tu archivo de texto `FFN` siempre se encuentra en la misma posición y el número a continuación tiene la misma cantidad de cifras. En caso contrario te devolverá datos erróneos.

Puedes probar también con el modulo `re`, con el que puedes buscar patrones en textos.

Por ejemplo partiendo de:

```
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1993201
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1993
STX01QFDQIN0YNQLFNSYNFFN344493201
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN19GG3201
STX01QF0SYNQLFNSYNFFN1N201
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN199-01
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN4
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFNP8
```

En tu código no devolvería lo que buscas, pero con `re.search` puedes evitar esos problemas:

```
import re

with open(r"archivo.txt", 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        x = re.search('(?<=FFN)\d+',line) #Busca cualquier numero precedido por FFN
        if x: #Si encuentra coincidencia la imprime
            print(x.group(0))
```

En este caso te devolvería lo siguiente:

```
1993201
1993
344493201
19
1
199
4
```